# Count by months in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you count the total number of entries by month?

```
id, date

01, 2010-09-28
02, 2010-03-28
03, 2010-09-28
04, 2010-03-28
```

For example. How could you pick only dates from September and have them count as an output of `2`?

Edit: Edited the dates to put them in the right format.

Comment: Surely you must have tried some SQL query in attempting to answer this?

Comment: `where year(date) = 2010 and month(date) = 9`, and pretty much exactly the same thing for a `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  month(date) , count(*)
from yourtable
group by month(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Still new to MySQL and wanted to test my own tables. Sorry to cause any trouble.

Here's the simple solution to my problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE)
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE month(DATE) = 9;
```